# Table: filter not working with decimal values

Tags: tables, csvsimple, filter

I have a filter that works with the first filecontents, but **not the second.** In fact, the filter doesn't work as soon as there is a decimal in the values that are going in the table.

Does anybody have a clue to why that is? And how can I fix this? The end goal is to create a filter that will take p values under 0.05 from an excel sheet, so the decimals are very important.

Thank you very much!
PS: someone commented that it's because the \ifnum does not work with floating point numbers, but then what could I do to still be able to filter values with decimals without the ifthen?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple,filecontents,longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents*}{random.csv}
A,B,C

egfwgt,39,ery

wrgsreh,3645467,yfghs

rshgtesh,346,rsth

ethshs,365,sty

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{random2.csv}
A,B,C

egfwgt,39.5,ery

wrgsreh,3645467,yfghs

rshgtesh,346,rsth

ethshs,365,sty

\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}


            \csvreader 
                [tabular=ccc,
                table head= \toprule A & B & C \\ \midrule,
                late after line= \\,
                table foot= \bottomrule, %very important to put line at bottom
               filter=\B<347,
                ]%
                {random.csv}{A=\A, B=\B, C=\C}%
                {\A  & \B & \C}

\csvreader 
                [tabular=ccc,
                table head= \toprule A & B & C \\ \midrule,
                late after line= \\,
                table foot= \bottomrule, %very important to put line at bottom
               filter=\B<347,
                ]%
                {random2.csv}{A=\A, B=\B, C=\C}%
                {\A  & \B & \C}


\end{document}
```

Comment: That's because `\ifnum` does not work with floating point numbers

Comment: Thank you! So what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a trick described in page 18 of the `csvsimple` manual, i.e. transform your column in a dimension for the filter and use `\ifdimless` with `full filter`

e.g. `full filter=\ifdimless{\B sp}{347 sp}{\csvfilteraccept}{\csvfilterreject}`

**NOTE**
I had to use scaled points due to the very large value `3645467` which is out of the range of normal points.

It's my understanding that scale points are dealt with (in normal LaTeX) as integers. So if your filter is bound to be a decimal number (e.g. < 40.5) I think that `sp`s won't work and you have to resort to `pt`s or something like that, which is bound to be (with etex) <=16384. So if your filter is decimal AND your values span above this  quantity, I think you cannot use `csvsimple`

**END NOTE**

See code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple,filecontents,longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents*}{random.csv}
A,B,C

egfwgt,39,ery

wrgsreh,3645467,yfghs

rshgtesh,346,rsth

ethshs,365,sty

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{random2.csv}
A,B,C

egfwgt,39.5,ery

wrgsreh,3645467,yfghs

rshgtesh,346,rsth

ethshs,365,sty

\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}


            \csvreader 
                [tabular=ccc,
                table head= \toprule A & B & C \\ \midrule,
                late after line= \\,
                table foot= \bottomrule, %very important to put line at bottom
               filter=\B<347,
                ]%
                {random.csv}{A=\A, B=\B, C=\C}%
                {\A  & \B & \C}

\csvreader 
                [tabular=ccc,
                table head= \toprule A & B & C \\ \midrule,
                late after line= \\,
                table foot= \bottomrule, %very important to put line at bottom
               full filter=\ifdimless{\B sp}{347sp}{\csvfilteraccept}{\csvfilterreject}%
                ]%
                {random2.csv}{A=\A, B=\B, C=\C}%
                {\A  & \B & \C}


\end{document}
```

with result

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly on a Windows computer. However, this doesn't work on the Mac version of the application. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @ValerieDesjardins I have a mac, and works like a charm for me. Are you sure about your TeX installation on the mac?

Comment: Do you mind telling me what version and date of your LaTeX application is?

Comment: @ValerieDesjardins I have standard TeX Live 2016, updated a couple of weeks ago

Comment: I just updated it, and I have the 2016 version, and it's still not working.. I don't know what it can be at this point

Comment: @ValerieDesjardins any errors? What's the output?

Comment: It says: "Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '\csvreader fill filter', to which you passed '\ifdimless{\Bsp}{347sp}{\csvfilteraccept}{\csvfilterreject}', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it."

Comment: @ValerieDesjardins `full filter` not `fill filter`

Comment: yeah sorry I did write full,  it was just a typo recopying the error!

Comment: @ValerieDesjardins the space between `\B` and `sp` `\B sp` and not `\Bsp`. Check the typos plz